# Computing and plotting difference in group means

Tags: stata, mean

In what follows I plot the mean of an outcome of interest (`price`) by a grouping variable (`foreign`) for each possible value taken by the fake variable `time`:

```
sysuse auto, clear

gen time = rep78 - 3
bysort foreign time: egen avg_p = mean(price) 

scatter avg_p time if (foreign==0 & time>=0) || ///
scatter avg_p time if (foreign==1 & time>=0), ///
    legend(order(1 "Domestic" 2 "Foreign")) ///
    ytitle("Average price") xlab(#3)
```

What I would like to do is to plot the difference in the two group means over time, not the two separate means. 
I am surely missing something, but to me it looks complicated because the information about the averages is stored "vertically" (in `avg_p`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to arguably use linear regression to estimate the differences:

```
/* Regression Way */
drop if time < 0 | missing(time)
reg price i.foreign##i.time
margins, dydx(foreign) at(time =(0(1)2))
marginsplot, noci title("Foreign vs Domestic Difference in Price")
```

If regression is hard to wrap your mind around, the other is involves mangling the data with a `reshape`:

```
/* Transform the Data */
keep price time foreign
collapse (mean) price, by(time foreign)
reshape wide price, i(time) j(foreign)
gen diff = price1-price0
tw connected diff time
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. `graph dot` will happily plot means.

```
sysuse auto, clear
set scheme s1color 
collapse price if inrange(rep78, 3, 5), by(foreign rep78) 
reshape wide price, i(rep78) j(foreign)
rename price0 Domestic 
label var Domestic 
rename price1 Foreign 
label var Foreign 
graph dot (asis) Domestic Foreign, over(rep78) vertical ///
marker(1, ms(Oh)) marker(2, ms(+))
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the difference in the means, rather than the means.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I fear that you are correct. But this graph does show differences, encoded as vertical distances between means; by showing the context of the means it shows context that data analysts should want to see; and others reading this thread may have concerns not quite identical to those  of the OP. How best to plot such data is naturally a little off-topic here, but the Stata technique remains.